# android fabrics reporting crash but the exact line number is not shown

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, google-fabric

Used fabrics to get the crash report but it is not showing the exact line number in the report. Finds difficult to identify the line of code if the class is too large.

Comment: Will you share screenshot here ? You can use https://imgbb.com/ as you have low reputations right now.

Comment: please share crash report

Comment: fabrics dashboard crash report - https://ibb.co/bL8xR9
https://ibb.co/gkoaDp

Comment: You need to upload mapping file to Play store.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit ProGuard settings. Add this line:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

to you ProGuard config file. More info here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html